# How to upgrade Minor versions of PostgreSQL on CentOS

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade the existing postgressql 11.2 to 11.4 on centos.

I have certain questions if i need to use pg_upgrade i need to install bew server and make it available for the migration.

Is there any simpler way in which i can just copy the new binary on existing one and try t start it. Will it be good enough what other process i need to follow for database upgrade.

I have tried with pg_upgrade and that works but its lengthy process  and need to install new server everytime and rename the directories and all.

Answer (score 2):

A minor version upgrade does not need `pg_upgrade`.

All you need to do is upgrade the binaries using:

```
yum update postgresql11
```

Then restart the Postgres service (the exact command depends on your CentOS version):

```
systemctl restart postgresql-11.service
```

Comment: ye but my issue is we are not using yum packages to install. So basically we are using Ansible scripts whihc deploys the binary on host. We download the binaries and extract the software and then deploy it according tour environment. So basically i want to ask if i can just overwrite the existing binary with new minor version and start the database will it work ? or anything else i need to take care on system tables level.

Comment: @aniketwalke: yes, you can just overwrite the binaries.